# vim script: working with the visual selection as well as the word under cursor

Tags: ruby, vim, markdown

I have a [small vim script](https://github.com/roma1n/vim-googurl) that queries Google to insert links in markdown-formatted text. Currently it only works using the word under cursor, which it retrieves using `expand("<cword>")` and modifies by executing normal mode commands (`norm ciw<new_text>`).

How could I modify this script so that it works using the visual selection if it exists?

I need basically three things:

- know whether text is being selected (otherwise use the word under cursor)
- retrieve the selected text
- modify the selected text

Ideally I would like a clean way to do this.

Any hints?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this case cleanly using a separate visual-mode mapping (`vnoremap` rather than `nnoremap`) that calls the same underlying function.

To extract the text, the markers `< and `> (for the start and end of the previous visual selection) may be useful.

To modify the text, you may be able to use `gv` from your script (re-select the previous visual selection) and then delete or replace it as you wish.

Hope this helps for now; I'll be able to spend a bit more time on it later.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I ended up coding the visual selection mode by using normal commands only. This is my first vim plugin, so any advice/tips/critique is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your visual selection extraction function is too complex. The usual way to proceed is the following: [`lh#visual#selection()`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/vim-lib/trunk/autoload/lh/visual.vim#29).

BTW, you can build the normal mode mapping with:

```
vnoremap µ :call <sid>DoStuff()<cr>
nmap µ viwµ
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! What are the hashes in `lh#visual#selection()`? A namespacing scheme?

Comment: Somehow yes. This is related to autoload plugins which serve several purposes : - defining library plugins ; - defining plugins that are loaded on-the-fly.